# Regex to remove leading and trailing spaces inside grave accents

Tags: php, regex

Please someone here correct my regex, I am trying to remove spaces inside grave accents

**My string looks like this**

```
`table_gis`.` latitude`  = -7.759 AND CONCAT(`table_gis`.smsx,'_',`table_gis`.`   stns   `)  IN ('SPX_0104','SDSX_133') AND
```

**This is my regex**

```
preg_replace('/([`])([\s]+)([\w]+)([`])/', "$1$3$4",$str)
```

**I get this output**

```
`table_gis`.`latitude`  = -7.759 AND CONCAT(`table_gis`.smsx,'_',`table_gis`.`   stns   `)  IN ('SPX_0104','SDSX_133') AND
```

**I expect this as output**

```
`table_gis`.`latitude`  = -7.759 AND CONCAT(`table_gis`.smsx,'_',`table_gis`.`stns`)  IN ('SPX_0104','SDSX_133') AND
```

How do I trim the word which is inside the grave accents ? someone guide me

Comment: Okay, I'll just ask it: Why on earth are you doing this? Can you not trim it *before* it is put into the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss to match the whitespace to the right of `\w+`.

You can add optional whitespace patterns on both side of `\w+` and use

```
`\s*(\w+)\s*`
```

and replace with `` `$1` ``

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tH1gZ7/1)

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/PGPJ8p):

```
$str = "`table_gis`.` latitude`  = -7.759 AND CONCAT(`table_gis`.smsx,'_',`table_gis`.`   stns   `)  IN ('SPX_0104','SDSX_133') AND"; 
$result = preg_replace('~`\s*(\w+)\s*`~', "`$1`", $str);
echo $result;
// => `table_gis`.`latitude`  = -7.759 AND CONCAT(`table_gis`.smsx,'_',`table_gis`.`stns`)  IN ('SPX_0104','SDSX_133') AND
```

If you do not want to match any `` `no_spaces_here` `` string (e.g. `` `table_gis` ``), you can use

```
(?|`\s+(\w+)\s*`|`\s*(\w+)\s+`)
```

([demo](https://regex101.com/r/tH1gZ7/2)) and replace with the same pattern as above (i.e. `` "`$1`" ``).

Comment: Glad it helps. Still, there is someone who thinks it does not.

Comment: @Downvoter, please post your solution Iif you don't agree with mine.

Comment: brother I think some people are jealous of you may be, since you posted answer early, no worry, I accepted it